# Display data from three SQL tables in a dataset using a parameter field

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am creating a SQL report with below queries from 3 different tables in one single dataset. And created a parameter name as @type. When i run the query it shows only the data from the first query in the report and no data coming from the second query.

Also in the Parameter @type Drop Down i gave names as Network Printer and Local Printer. For both its showing only the Network printers data.

Kindly help me on how do i achieve the complete data from both reports, and when selected the network Printer it should show network printers and when selected Local Printers it should show local printers.

```
SELECT V_GS_NETWORKPRINTERS0.ResourceID, DEV.Netbios_Name0 AS Netbios_Name, PrinterQueue0 AS PrinterName, PrintServer0 AS PrinterServer, 
PrinterLocation0 AS PrinterLocation, PrinterDriver0 AS PrinterDriver, DateInventoried0 AS Timestamp, 'Network Printer' AS Type FROM V_GS_NETWORKPRINTERS0
LEFT JOIN v_R_System_Valid DEV ON DEV.ResourceID = V_GS_NETWORKPRINTERS0.ResourceID ORDER BY DEV.Netbios_Name0

SELECT ResourceID, SystemName0 AS Netbios_Name, Caption0 AS PrinterName, SystemName0 AS PrinterServer, SystemName0 AS PrinterLocation,
DriverName0 AS PrinterDriver, TimeStamp AS Timestamp, 'Local Printer' AS Type FROM V_GS_PRINTER_DEVICE
ORDER BY PrinterName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT V_GS_NETWORKPRINTERS0.ResourceID, DEV.Netbios_Name0 AS Netbios_Name, PrinterQueue0 AS PrinterName, PrintServer0 AS PrinterServer, 
PrinterLocation0 AS PrinterLocation, PrinterDriver0 AS PrinterDriver, DateInventoried0 AS Timestamp, 'Network Printer' AS Type FROM V_GS_NETWORKPRINTERS0
LEFT JOIN v_R_System_Valid DEV ON DEV.ResourceID = V_GS_NETWORKPRINTERS0.ResourceID ORDER BY DEV.Netbios_Name0

UNION ALL

SELECT ResourceID, SystemName0 AS Netbios_Name, Caption0 AS PrinterName, SystemName0 AS PrinterServer, SystemName0 AS PrinterLocation,
DriverName0 AS PrinterDriver, TimeStamp AS Timestamp, 'Local Printer' AS Type FROM V_GS_PRINTER_DEVICE) as X
WHERE X.Type=@type
```

Try this. The "union all" joins the data set together, the top select statement treats the union all subquery as one dataset, then you add the parameter to the Where clause of the new union dataset.

Comment: When i run the query it is not giving any output. I also declared the @type on top of the query as

Comment: Declare @type Varchar;

Comment: You should **not** declare the variable in your query, this will be injected by SSRS. Make sure the Parameter.Value (not Parameter.Label) is 'Local Printer' or 'Network Printer'. If this does not help, show your parameter setup, both values and labels. Neil's solution will work if you pass the correct value to the query.

Comment: sorry for giving trouble as i am layman in SQL. In parameter properties -- Available values -- I added Label as Printer and the value same like you have provided  Parameter.Value (not Parameter.Label) is 'Local Printer' or 'Network Printer'

I am not getting any output

Comment: ok, at the last line of the code add -- in front of the where clause and then try the code, you should be getting data back. Make sure in your available values, the Values match exact to the values of the table, no spaces etc.

Comment: Thank you, Neil. Now i am getting all printers in one report. 
But in the Parameter tab, Drop down is there any way we can look only for Network printer or only for Local Printer

Comment: copy and paste a value for both Network and Local into the your parameter values - don't type them. The other way to guarantee the values is a bit silly but will guarantee the right values, which is to create a dataset from your original query that pulls back distinct Types and then the parameter uses these to get the values, by specifying "get values from query" then use the distinct column as both Value Field and Label Field.